# Getting memory of SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

I am using an in-memory SQLite database to store part of a configuration for use in copy/paste.  I need to be able to grab the memory to stream it to the clipboard and read it back in.  Does anyone know how to grab the memory?

Comment: That does sound quite tricky, since, among other things, you have to make sure that you get the database in a stable state. Can't you use online backup and restore?

Comment: Depending on what API you use to access the DB, there might also already exist an interface to dump /read individual tables in SQL format (i.e., SQL statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no mechanism to grab the actual memory of an in-memory database.

You could use the [backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) to copy the database to a temporary file, but then it might have been a better idea to create a file-based database in the first place.

Alternatively, it would be possible to write your own [VFS](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html) that stores the data in RAM instead of in a file.
However, this might be more effort than you want to spend.

Comment: I looked at the backup api, and came to the same conclusion as you; better off going straight to file.  The VFS approach is interesting, and might be worth trying when I am given more time.  Thanks.